# Should I use the foreign_key clause both in has_many as in belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models. `Office` and `Employee`. `Employee` has `office_id` as foreign_key. The tables was generated under a namespace. So, which is the correct?

```
class MyNamespace::Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees, foreign_key: 'office_id'
end

class MyNamespace::Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office, foreign_key: 'office_id'
end
```

Or

```
class MyNamespace::Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
end

class MyNamespace::Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office, foreign_key: 'office_id'
end
```

I think the second example is the correct, because to me, doesn't makes sense declare the foreign_key in a `has_many` relation. A coworker thinks the first example is the correct. But I haven't found too many references to this subject. So, does Anybody know which is the correct example and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify prefixes for proper mapping to table names in DB and remove foreign_keys and MyNamespace at all.

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name_prefix = 'namespace_'
  has_many :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name_prefix = 'namespace_'
  belongs_to :office
end
```

Comment: I updated my question. Because I forgot to mention that the tables was generated under a namespace, so, in the database the table are as `my_namespace_employee` and `my_namespace_office`. The model name doesn't matches the table name:/